# Cost Function of Neural Network (Forward Propagation)

Tags: machine-learning, estimation, logistic-regression, neural-networks

This question is related to **Andrew Ng's** machine learning course on Coursera. Basically, when I calculate the cost function of a neural network, I use the following formula that was described by Ng:
$$
J(\theta) = \frac 1m \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^k\begin{bmatrix}-y_k^{(i)}\log((h_\theta(x^{(i)}))_k) - (1-y_k^{(i)})\log(1-(h_\theta(x^{(i)}))_k)\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let's call:
\begin{align}
j_1 &= -y_k^{(i)}\log((h_\theta(x^{(i)}))_k)\\j_2&= - (1-y_k^{(i)})\log(1-(h_\theta(x^{(i)}))_k)\\j&= j_1+j_2
\end{align}
So the exercise asked me to convert any $y$ and $h_\theta(x)$ matrix into a binary matrix before performing the computation. Now this is when I don't understand...either I am getting it wrong or I am misunderstanding a concept.

If $y_k=0$ and $h_\theta(x)=0$ then $j_1=0, j_2=0, j=0$. Similarly

If $y_k=1$ and $h_\theta(x)=1$ then $j_1=0, j_2=0, j=0$.

Which seems fair since there should be no impact to the overall cost function.

How about...

If $y_k=1$ and $h_\theta(x)=0$ then $j_1$ is undefined since i cannot perform $\log(0)$.
? and also

If $y_k=0$ and $h_\theta(x)=1$ then I will also face the $\log(0)$ problem?

I think I am interpreting something wrongly but am not sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the output of the neural network is to be interpreted as a probability distribution (e.g. over $K$ visual object categories), the final layer is typically a [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function):
$$
h_\theta(x)_k = \frac{e^{z_k(x)}}{\sum_{j=1}^K e^{z_j(x)}}
$$
where each $z_j$ is a "neuron activation", which itself is a differentiable function of the input $x$.

Now notice that the softmax is always positive for finite inputs $z_k$. That is, we can never have $h_\theta(x) = 0$ (although it can be very small, and this can lead to numerical problems).

Similarly, the softmax cannot output values that are exactly equal to $1$, for finite inputs.

Comment: Yes you are so correct! My mistake was that I took the highest probability of $(h_\theta(x)) and assigned that value 1. I should have used the probability. Finally this is solved! Moving on!